# Problems installing cytoolz on Python@3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, vyper

I am trying to install `cytoolz` in `virtualenv`:

1. `Python` version = `3.10.0`
2. `Pip` version = `21.3.1`

After running `pip install cytoolz` in the **activated** virtualenv I am getting the following log:

```
Collecting cytoolz
  Using cached cytoolz-0.11.0.tar.gz (477 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: toolz>=0.8.0 in ./env/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from cytoolz) (0.11.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: cytoolz
  Building wheel for cytoolz (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/hristotodorov/Documents/Vyper/env/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/5y/q2vqps3s0jq7nc73z2zgmpmr0000gn/T/pip-install-0ebpvw2k/cytoolz_455f12fc06374667a15ffeeafa952f0f/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/5y/q2vqps3s0jq7nc73z2zgmpmr0000gn/T/pip-install-0ebpvw2k/cytoolz_455f12fc06374667a15ffeeafa952f0f/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/5y/q2vqps3s0jq7nc73z2zgmpmr0000gn/T/pip-wheel-czxvyqb8
       cwd: /private/var/folders/5y/q2vqps3s0jq7nc73z2zgmpmr0000gn/T/pip-install-0ebpvw2k/cytoolz_455f12fc06374667a15ffeeafa952f0f/
  Complete output (75 lines):
  ALERT: Cython not installed.  Building without Cython.
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/compatibility.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/utils_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/_signatures.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/curried
  copying cytoolz/curried/operator.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/curried
  copying cytoolz/curried/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/curried
  copying cytoolz/curried/exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/curried
  copying cytoolz/itertoolz.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/dicttoolz.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/functoolz.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/recipes.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/utils.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/utils.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/recipes.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/functoolz.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/dicttoolz.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/cpython.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
  copying cytoolz/itertoolz.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_none_safe.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_curried.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_compatibility.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_embedded_sigs.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_functoolz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_inspect_args.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_doctests.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_tlz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_signatures.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/dev_skip_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_recipes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_docstrings.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_dev_skip_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_dicttoolz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_serialization.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_curried_toolzlike.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
  copying cytoolz/tests/test_itertoolz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
  running build_ext
  building 'cytoolz.dicttoolz' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Users/hristotodorov/Documents/Vyper/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10 -c cytoolz/dicttoolz.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/dicttoolz.o
  clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/dicttoolz.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/dicttoolz.cpython-310-darwin.so
  building 'cytoolz.functoolz' extension
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Users/hristotodorov/Documents/Vyper/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10 -c cytoolz/functoolz.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/functoolz.o
  cytoolz/functoolz.c:23087:19: error: implicit declaration of function '_PyGen_Send' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
              ret = _PyGen_Send((PyGenObject*)yf, value == Py_None ? NULL : value);
                    ^
  cytoolz/functoolz.c:23087:17: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'PyObject *' (aka 'struct _object *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
              ret = _PyGen_Send((PyGenObject*)yf, value == Py_None ? NULL : value);
                  ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cytoolz/functoolz.c:23092:19: error: implicit declaration of function '_PyGen_Send' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
              ret = _PyGen_Send((PyGenObject*)yf, value == Py_None ? NULL : value);
                    ^
  cytoolz/functoolz.c:23092:17: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'PyObject *' (aka 'struct _object *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
              ret = _PyGen_Send((PyGenObject*)yf, value == Py_None ? NULL : value);
                  ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cytoolz/functoolz.c:23176:19: error: implicit declaration of function '_PyGen_Send' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
              ret = _PyGen_Send((PyGenObject*)yf, NULL);
                    ^
  cytoolz/functoolz.c:23176:17: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'PyObject *' (aka 'struct _object *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
              ret = _PyGen_Send((PyGenObject*)yf, NULL);
                  ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  3 warnings and 3 errors generated.
  error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cytoolz
  Running setup.py clean for cytoolz
Failed to build cytoolz
Installing collected packages: cytoolz
    Running setup.py install for cytoolz ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/hristotodorov/Documents/Vyper/env/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/5y/q2vqps3s0jq7nc73z2zgmpmr0000gn/T/pip-install-0ebpvw2k/cytoolz_455f12fc06374667a15ffeeafa952f0f/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/5y/q2vqps3s0jq7nc73z2zgmpmr0000gn/T/pip-install-0ebpvw2k/cytoolz_455f12fc06374667a15ffeeafa952f0f/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/5y/q2vqps3s0jq7nc73z2zgmpmr0000gn/T/pip-record-s_w__7qh/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/hristotodorov/Documents/Vyper/env/include/site/python3.10/cytoolz
         cwd: /private/var/folders/5y/q2vqps3s0jq7nc73z2zgmpmr0000gn/T/pip-install-0ebpvw2k/cytoolz_455f12fc06374667a15ffeeafa952f0f/
    Complete output (77 lines):
    ALERT: Cython not installed.  Building without Cython.
    running install
    /Users/hristotodorov/Documents/Vyper/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
    copying cytoolz/compatibility.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
    copying cytoolz/utils_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
    copying cytoolz/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
    copying cytoolz/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
    copying cytoolz/_signatures.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/curried
    copying cytoolz/curried/operator.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/curried
    copying cytoolz/curried/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/curried
    copying cytoolz/curried/exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/curried
    copying cytoolz/itertoolz.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
    copying cytoolz/dicttoolz.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
    copying cytoolz/functoolz.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
    copying cytoolz/recipes.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
    copying cytoolz/utils.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
    copying cytoolz/utils.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
    copying cytoolz/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
    copying cytoolz/recipes.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
    copying cytoolz/functoolz.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
    copying cytoolz/dicttoolz.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
    copying cytoolz/cpython.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
    copying cytoolz/itertoolz.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
    copying cytoolz/tests/test_none_safe.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
    copying cytoolz/tests/test_utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
    copying cytoolz/tests/test_curried.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
    copying cytoolz/tests/test_compatibility.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
    copying cytoolz/tests/test_embedded_sigs.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
    copying cytoolz/tests/test_functoolz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
    copying cytoolz/tests/test_inspect_args.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
    copying cytoolz/tests/test_doctests.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
    copying cytoolz/tests/test_tlz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
    copying cytoolz/tests/test_signatures.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
    copying cytoolz/tests/dev_skip_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
    copying cytoolz/tests/test_recipes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
    copying cytoolz/tests/test_docstrings.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
    copying cytoolz/tests/test_dev_skip_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
    copying cytoolz/tests/test_dicttoolz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
    copying cytoolz/tests/test_serialization.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
    copying cytoolz/tests/test_curried_toolzlike.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
    copying cytoolz/tests/test_itertoolz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests
    running build_ext
    building 'cytoolz.dicttoolz' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Users/hristotodorov/Documents/Vyper/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10 -c cytoolz/dicttoolz.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/dicttoolz.o
    clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/dicttoolz.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/dicttoolz.cpython-310-darwin.so
    building 'cytoolz.functoolz' extension
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Users/hristotodorov/Documents/Vyper/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10 -c cytoolz/functoolz.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/functoolz.o
    cytoolz/functoolz.c:23087:19: error: implicit declaration of function '_PyGen_Send' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                ret = _PyGen_Send((PyGenObject*)yf, value == Py_None ? NULL : value);
                      ^
    cytoolz/functoolz.c:23087:17: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'PyObject *' (aka 'struct _object *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
                ret = _PyGen_Send((PyGenObject*)yf, value == Py_None ? NULL : value);
                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    cytoolz/functoolz.c:23092:19: error: implicit declaration of function '_PyGen_Send' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                ret = _PyGen_Send((PyGenObject*)yf, value == Py_None ? NULL : value);
                      ^
    cytoolz/functoolz.c:23092:17: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'PyObject *' (aka 'struct _object *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
                ret = _PyGen_Send((PyGenObject*)yf, value == Py_None ? NULL : value);
                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    cytoolz/functoolz.c:23176:19: error: implicit declaration of function '_PyGen_Send' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                ret = _PyGen_Send((PyGenObject*)yf, NULL);
                      ^
    cytoolz/functoolz.c:23176:17: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'PyObject *' (aka 'struct _object *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
                ret = _PyGen_Send((PyGenObject*)yf, NULL);
                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    3 warnings and 3 errors generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/hristotodorov/Documents/Vyper/env/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/5y/q2vqps3s0jq7nc73z2zgmpmr0000gn/T/pip-install-0ebpvw2k/cytoolz_455f12fc06374667a15ffeeafa952f0f/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/5y/q2vqps3s0jq7nc73z2zgmpmr0000gn/T/pip-install-0ebpvw2k/cytoolz_455f12fc06374667a15ffeeafa952f0f/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/5y/q2vqps3s0jq7nc73z2zgmpmr0000gn/T/pip-record-s_w__7qh/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/hristotodorov/Documents/Vyper/env/include/site/python3.10/cytoolz Check the logs for full command output.
```

It appears that there is a problem with the installation of the `cytoolz` package.
Running `pip install cytoolz` produces the same error.
How can I fix that?

Edit: As mention bellow in the comments the problem is not in the `eth-brownie` but in the `cytoolz`. [Here](https://github.com/pytoolz/cytoolz/issues/151) you can find an open issue in Github.

Comment: So the problem is with cytoolz not eth-brownie. Why don't you report it as an issue on GitHub? Stackoverflow is not an issue board.

Comment: Yes, I doubt the SO community can provide anything other than votes on the post unfortunately.

Comment: Report your bug here https://github.com/pytoolz/cytoolz

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have open an issue and updated the question

Answer (score 0):

install cython first
`pip install cython` and then install brownie. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned bellow in the comments of the question the problem is not in the `eth-brownie` but in the `cytoolz`. [Here](https://github.com/pytoolz/cytoolz/issues/151) you can find an open issue in Github.

Answer (score -2):

@Abhay Katheria got this. worked for me too.
if it does not work still, try downloading "Microsoft C++ Build Tools" first, check (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcI1_e38BWs) for how to download it on windows.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31418854)